# Unable to access any route besides "/" in a Vue app hosted on Azure, with the message, "The requested content does not exist"

Tags: javascript, azure, vue.js, vue-router

I have an application built with Vue, hosted on Azure, but when I build it I can't access any routes besides "/", for some reason. All it shows me is a message saying: "*The requested content does not exist*," when I try to access other routes

I've tried switching the view router mode between `history` and `hash`, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. Any suggestions are welcome.

Here's my code

```
// index.js

import Router from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
```

```
// routes.js

import LoginMain from '@/components/login/LoginMain'
import Conveniados from '@/components/conveniados/Conveniados'
import Logout from '@/components/login/Logout'

import Categorias from '@/components/categorias/Categorias'
import Historico from '@/components/historico/Historico'
import Ofertas from '@/components/ofertas/Ofertas'
import Usuarios from '@/components/usuarios/Usuarios'
import Clubes from '@/components/clube/Clubes'
import Voucher from '@/components/voucher/Voucher'
import Pedidos from '@/components/pedidos/Pedidos'
import Produtos from '@/components/produtos/Produtos'
import ConveniadoOfertas from '@/components/conveniados-ofertas/ConvOfertas'
import Delivery from '@/components/delivery/Delivery'
import i18n from '../i18n'

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: LoginMain
  },
  {
    path: '/logout',
    component: Logout
  },
  {
    path: '/conveniados',
    component: Conveniados,
    name: 'conveniados',
    alias: `${i18n.t('associate')}`,
    nivel: 2
  },
  {
    path: '/conveniado/:uuidConveniado/ofertas',
    component: ConveniadoOfertas,
    name: 'conveniadosOfertas',
    alias: 'ConveniadoOfertas'
  },
  {
    path: '/ofertas',
    component: Ofertas,
    name: 'ofertas',
    alias: `${i18n.t('offers')}`,
    nivel: 2
  },
  {
    path: '/produtos',
    component: Produtos,
    name: 'produtos',
    alias: `${i18n.t('products')}`,
    nivel: 2
  },
  {
    path: '/pedidos',
    component: Pedidos,
    name: 'pedidos',
    alias: `${i18n.t('orders')}`,
    nivel: 2,
    notify: true
  },
  {
    path: '/categorias',
    component: Categorias,
    name: 'categorias',
    alias: `${i18n.t('categories')}`,
    nivel: 1
  },
  {
    path: '/historico',
    component: Historico,
    name: 'historico',
    alias: `${i18n.t('historic')}`,
    nivel: 2
  },
  {
    path: '/usuarios',
    component: Usuarios,
    name: 'usuarios',
    alias: `${i18n.t('users')}`,
    nivel: 1
  },
  {
    path: '/clubes',
    component: Clubes,
    name: 'clubes',
    alias: 'Clubes',
    nivel: 1
  },
  {
    path: '/voucher',
    component: Voucher,
    name: 'voucher',
    alias: 'Voucher',
    nivel: 1
  },
  {
    path: '/delivery',
    component: Delivery,
    name: 'delivery',
    alias: `${i18n.t('delivery')}`,
    nivel: 1
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/'
  }
]
```